# Will vs would usage differences

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

> 1. What **will** you do if you find a suitcase with $10,000?
> 2. What **would** you do if you found a suitcase with $10,000?

I know that first sentence is normal and second sentence is hypothetical and imaginary. But as I am a non-native speaker and I am a bit confused about their usage.

Question 1: Can we randomly ask this question to our friend or some other person we know in the normal realistic form like sentence 1 or we can’t use sentence 1 as finding a suitcase with $10,000 is unlikely and this is a hypothetical case?

Question 2: How does a listener think differently for these two different forms of questions mentioned? Does asking him in sentence 1 form, makes him to expect finding a suitcase with $10,000, as sentence is not in hypothetical form?

Answer (score 1):

*What will you do if...* implies that you think something is quite likely to happen ('if it rains').

*What would you do if...*, as you say, is more likely to be used with a hypothetical situation.

Of course you *can* ask someone what they 'will do' if something unlikely happens, but it would sound strange.